# Using jquery to change a css rule

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following css rule:

```
.headerWrapperDiv3 a{
    color:#888;
}
.headerWrapperDiv3 a:hover {
    color:#444;
}
```

and the following markup:

```
<div class='headerWrapperDiv3'>
<ul class="nav90">
    <li><a href="index.aspx" pageCatID="3" >Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and I'm using this jQuery to change the color of the link once the page loads:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[pageCatID=3]").each(function(){
        $(this).css("color", "#00ff00");
    });
});
```

The jquery finds the link ok but fails to change the color.

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccru5us1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (surround the value by single quotation marks):

```
$(function() {
    $("a[pageCatID='3']").each(function(){
        $(this).css("color", "#00ff00");
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. There was me thinking I had a specifity problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try the example below

```
 $(function() {
        $(".nav90 a").each(function(){
            $(this).css("color", "#00ff00");
        });
    })
```

**Solution:** As shown above, just target **.nav90** and the **a** inside.

**Note:** If you want more specificity, adhere to the corrections made to your code by Rodrigo and you'll be just fine.

Comment: Given that the OP is building a nav, I would assume the `<ul>` will have additional `<li>`'s with more `<a>`'s in them... this would apply the change to all of the `<a>`'s within the `<ul class="nav90">`

Comment: Make a difference with page ID. it's that simple

Answer (score 1):

> Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C
>   CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid
>   identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks.

```
$("a[pageCatID='3']").each(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "#00ff00");
});
```

As you see you need to suround `3` with quotation marks.

Comment: @NiMa: It's an attribute selector. `a[pageCatID='3']` selects all anchor elements with the attribute `pageCatID` set to `3`.

Comment: it finds the links with the attribute pageCatID set to the value of 3

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use .each, selectors apply to every object:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[pageCatID=3]").css("color", "#00ff00");
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mu54yjn4/

**UPDATE:**

For more than one property:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[pageCatID=3]").css({
        "color": "#00ff00",
        "background-color": "#000"
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zf6fjz0q/

Comment: ok. now if i was to change more than just the color, ie background and font style as well would it be more efficient to use each rather than 3 selector commands?